# how to update time in table when anyone close its browser - mysql and codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, session, browser

i am developing a website in codeigniter and i have a session table in my mysql and in this table i have store session id when anyone come to my website and current time now i want to update this table when that user leave my website mean when user close its browser i want to update my table with that current time and also want to update status field with 0 that was current has default value is 1
can anyone have idea how to handle this situation

```
$datasess = array(
    'session_id' => $session_id,
    'session_ip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
    'last_accessed' => $session_accesstime,
    'session_exit' => '',
    'status' => '1'
    );
```

Comment: You might solve it with javascript, see http://api.jquery.com/unload/ Using the unload event to trigger an AJAX call.

Answer (score 2):

Catch the `unload` event and send the ajax request to your server.

Like this

```
$(window).unload(function() {
  //Place an ajax request here  
});
```